# How to Automate or Move (Silverlight) xap file to 14 hive ClientBin

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-enterprise, silverlight

I am using silverlight project in sharepoint 2010.I have an requirement of using WSP builder project only for building the soultion and I have configured the layout structure as shown below.

[image]

In the dev machine I have configured **post build event command** in the project properties tab 
**xcopy Sample.xap "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ClientBin\" /Y**

So whenever I build the silverlight project automatically the sample.xap file will be moved to the 14 hive client bin but when I build WSP for the project using wsp builder the clientbin folder is not available in it. But when I right click the clientbin folder in visual studio solution the sample.xap file is present but inside the wsp it is not there ?

So could you provide a solution for automate or move the xap file to 14 hive clientbin folder at the time of deploying the wsp in the testing server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure silverlight project to move file to ../Layouts/ClientBin of your WSP Builder project, when WSP Builder creates a package it will pack it correctly.

This can help you understand the approach in details with UserControls, the same will be for xap files - http://www.greggalipeau.com/2009/05/18/developing-sharepoint-webparts-using-user-controls-and-web-applications/